# Any way to simplify the captcha challenge?

Tags: discussion

It took me nearly 1/2 hour to get into tor.stackexchange.com

The Captchas are, in my opinion, illegible.

I listened to the audio file but when the audio came up, the box to enter the answer disappeared.

Looks like something is wrong with the captcha system.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the Captchas are so difficult is because with Javascript disabled, your traffic looks more like bot traffic. I usually disable noscript or turn down the Tor slider to get through Cloudflare (as having scripts enabled makes Cloudflare instead show you a 3-4 digit long legible captcha image), though this can compromise anonymity. If this doesn't always work for you, find exit nodes that do allow the previous method (using `New Tor Identity`) a few times, and set Tor to use only those exit nodes in your `torrc` file [as described here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) under *ExitNodes node,node,…*

EDIT: Answer didn't fully make sense, sorry for the unclarity.

Comment: I'm not complaining that there is a captcha, I'm saying that the captcha is ILLEGIBLE. It is so heavily blurred that it is impossible to determine what letters are used.

Answer (score 0):

The **only** proper way is to make an onion entry point to whole StackExchange network.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain that? Your answer doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: @Scott The thing is, that there's a IDS(Intrusion Detection Systems)/IPS(Intrusion Prevention Systems) layer in ISP Datacenters to protect the hosted sites and servers. A reasonable thing, BUT in many "anonymous proxies" lists/checkers Tor exits are listed too. So - you can't disable this check, but shooting in your leg by encomplicating Tor user's life. To keep this check AND to make Tor user experience smooth and good - a hidden service must be launched for StackExchange. Some dot-onion address.